# Swift OpenWeatherMap API Value of type 'Any' error

Tags: ios, swift, api, openweathermap

Hey my swift code gives an error

> Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

in this line

```
if let weatherArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray {
print("Type \(weatherArray[0]["main"])")
}
```

I have no idea how to fix it I tried to search the web but I wasn't albo to find solution

The rest of code

```
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let weatherURL = url!
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherURL) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error:\n\(error)")
            }
            
        else {
            if let data = data {
                
                let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print("All the weather data:\n\(dataString!)")
                if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                    if let mainDictionary = jsonObj.value(forKey: "main") as? NSDictionary {
                        if let temperature = mainDictionary.value(forKey: "feels_like") {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                print("Feels like: \(temperature)°C")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if let weatherArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray {
                        print("Type \(weatherArray[0]["main"])")
                
                    }
```

Comment: You need to cast `weatherArray[0]` first before accessing it further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let weatherArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray {
    print("Type \(weatherArray[0]["main"])")
}
```

you have to cast your item to NSDictionary again

```
if let weatherArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray,
    let inner = weatherArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
        print("Type \(inner["main"])")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `weatherArray` is an array of uncasted values, similar to `[Any]`. When you try to evaluate `weatherArray[0]["main"]`, you're referencing the first element of type `Any` and try to get something with subscript, but `Any` doesn't implement one so you get an error.